# Make status bar appear normally when showing a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-statusbar

I have a DialogFragment at the top of the screen:

[image]

I would like to see the Status bar as I normally would, without the overlay (while keeping it for the rest of the screen)
This is what I'm trying in the AppCompatDialog, without success:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Window window = getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        }
        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you show a dialog, it has a shadow in the background. I recommend not using the API window with clearFlags/addFlags because they are a bit messy sometimes but rather to directly remove this shadow.

Assuming your dialog variable is *dialog*, you just call this method on it and you have removed the shadow:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything, unfortunately. Also, I'd like to keep the rest of the screen faded.